# I want to build multidimensional array at Twig

Tags: theming

I want to build multidimensional  array at Twig.

In php

```
 $attributes['attributes']['class'] = array();
 $attributes['attributes']['class'][] = 'innerTab';
 $attributes['html'] = TRUE;
```

Same thing I want to build in Twig.
I tried but not getting proper one . Please check my code below

```
 {% set ctn = 0 %}
         {% for key, value in menu.menu %}
{% set attributes = {'attributes':'class'} %}
{% set attributes = attributes|merge( [ { (ctn) :'innerTab'} ,  {'html' : true} ]  ) %} 
{% set ctn = ctn+1  %}
 {% endfor %}
```

As a result I get :

> array(3) { ["attributes"]=> string(5) "class" [0]=> array(1) { [0]=>
>   string(8) "innerTab" } [1]=> array(1) { ["html"]=> bool(true) } }
>   array(3) { ["attributes"]=> string(5) "class" [0]=> array(1) { [1]=>
>   string(8) "innerTab" } [1]=> array(1) { ["html"]=> bool(true) } }
>   array(3) { ["attributes"]=> string(5) "class" [0]=> array(1) { [2]=>
>   string(8) "innerTab" } [1]=> array(1) { ["html"]=> bool(true) } }

Comment: I think it’s easier to create the array in a preprocess function and then loop through it in twig.

Comment: Yes, Twig is designed for objects, not for arrays and Drupal still has a lot of arrays. But this can be done in Twig, you only have to start backwards with the loop for the lowest level and then put the array together, because merge can only merge one level at a time.

Comment: Although for attributes you can use an object now, see https://www.drupal.org/node/2818293

Comment: In Drupal 7 .. I used  `$menu_tabs .= l($title, $href, $attributes);` to concatenate urls .  But in drupal 8 inside twig I can't use   `{% set menu_tabs ~= link(title,support_url,attributes) %}` . I also try with marge as link return array but not working.. Please help me

Comment: The link() function accepts both, an attributes array or an Attribute object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Drupal 8 use an [Attribute](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Template%21Attribute.php/class/Attribute/8.7.x) object instead of a multidimensional array:

D7 PHP:

```
$attributes['attributes']['class'] = array();
$attributes['attributes']['class'][] = 'innerTab';
```

D8 Twig:

```
{% set attributes = create_attribute() %}
{% set attributes = attributes.addClass('innerTab') %}
```

You can use the Attribute object in Twig `link()`:

```
{{ link(title, support_url, attributes) }}
```